# Set a default root path for compiled elements on a Vue App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I build my Vue app, all compiled files (vendor.js, client.js, manifest.js, client.css) are called inside index.html with the root path /vendor.js, /client.js, manifest.js and /client.js

I would like to specify a root path in the project in order to be compiled with my server path.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have your current webpack config?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the public path by changing the output parameter in the webpack configuration.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath

```
publicPath: "https://cdn.example.com/assets/", // CDN (always HTTPS)
publicPath: "//cdn.example.com/assets/", // CDN (same protocol)
publicPath: "/assets/", // server-relative
publicPath: "assets/", // relative to HTML page
publicPath: "../assets/", // relative to HTML page
publicPath: "", // relative to HTML page (same directory)
```